# MinLines and MaxLines on TextBox not working

Tags: wpf, xaml, textbox

Can anyone explain why the following TextBox doesn't initially display as 3 lines high? It displays 1 line high and then adjusts to 3 when I start typing text.

Edit: Here's some more of the form

```
<Window x:Class="MyNamespace.Views.DetailsView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:MV="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Views"
    xmlns:prop="clr-namespace:MyNamespace.Properties"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit"
    MV:DialogCloser.DialogResult="{Binding Path=DialogResult, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Background="{StaticResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}" 
    Title="{Binding Source={x:Static prop:Resources.MyView_Caption}}"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" 
    WindowStyle="SingleBorderWindow" 
    MinHeight="100" 
    MinWidth="250">
<StackPanel Name="AllItems" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <StackPanel Width="450" Margin="5">
        <StackPanel Margin="5,0,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <DockPanel Margin="5" >
                <Label Content="Prompt"/>
                <TextBox MaxLines="3"
                     MinLines="3" 
                     VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                     TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            </DockPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
...
</Window>
```

Comment: When I paste your code in XamlPadX the TextBox is displayed with 3 lines

Comment: Works for me too, your problem is elsewhere. Post more of the containing xaml?

Comment: I faced the same problem (not working)

Comment: Apparently this is a bug in the Windows 8/10 runtime since in Windows 7/XP it doesn't have this behaviour. BTW, it's still not fixed in .NET 4.6.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, i have too faced this problem. The TextBox will not initially be sized properly at startup and you can workaround this by binding the Text property with an startup text(Say a balnk space value " ").

XAML:

```
<StackPanel Margin="5,0,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
 <DockPanel Margin="5" >
 <Label Content="Prompt"/>
 <TextBox MaxLines="3"
         MinLines="3" x:Name="text"
         VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
         Text="{Binding StartUpText}"
         AcceptsReturn="True"
         TextWrapping="Wrap" TextChanged="text_TextChanged" Loaded="text_Loaded"  />
 </DockPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

C#:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext=this;
         StartUpText = " ";
    }

private string startUpText;
public string StartUpText
{
  get { return startUpText; }
  set
  {
    if (value != startUpText)
    {
        startUpText = value;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you understand why it happens? We shouldn't need to do this workaround. I'd really rather not put spaces in and trim them out.

Comment: i'm not sure about the reason, i guess its a bug with TextBox Maxline Property

Answer (score 0):

You can use also FallbackValue on Text:

```
<StackPanel Margin="5,0,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
     <DockPanel Margin="5" >
          <Label Content="Prompt"/>
          <TextBox MaxLines="3"
              MinLines="3" x:Name="text"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              Text="{Binding StartUpText, FallbackValue=whatyouwant}"
              AcceptsReturn="True"
              TextWrapping="Wrap" TextChanged="text_TextChanged" Loaded="text_Loaded"  />
     </DockPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Setting the fallback value doesn't always work either. For instance, a zero-length string will not trigger the needed layout, and using anything else means that value will be propagated to the UI before the bindings initialize against the data context.  Check out the answer I just posted that addresses these issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue caused by using Height property in combination with MaxLines.

"If the Height property is explicitly set on a TextBox, the MaxLines and MinLines property values are ignored. " 
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlines?view=netframework-4.8

This problem was solved by using the height so that only 5 lines can be typed in the given height

Comment: You shouldn't use any of the `Height` variants because they don't take into consideration font size, etc.  You really should let the control handle the sizing because it will take the font into consideration.  Check out the answer I just posted which does exactly that. There's a few things needed for the setup, but you only have to do that once per codebase.