# Set 2-Line text box

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox

#### Goal:

I'm trying to create a TextBox with space for exactly 2 lines.
The content will later be filled into a document which has a maximum space for two lines.

[image]

The user should be able to see that visually in the application to generate the Document:

[image]

#### Current Situation / Issue

The TextBox sits in a Grid with `<RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>`. This leads the Textbox to occupy exactly 1 Line of space (marked in yellow):
[image]

Only when the first letter is beeing typed, the textbox expands to two lines due to `MinLines="2"`. I do have the Idea to set a static height to the Grid.Row but to be honest, I really dislike static sizing and I feel that it is not the apropriate solution.

Additionally, eventhough `MaxLines="2"` the textbox will happily wrap around any number of lines.
I have set `MaxLength="200"` - It kind of does the Job but has nothing to do with the actual text size.
(iiiii vs WWWWW)

#### Current Code:

```
<Grid x:Name="EigenbelegGrid">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!-- Preset -->
    <Label Content="Preset" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"></Label>
    <ComboBox x:Name="TemplateSelection_DropDown" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" IsEditable="True"
    <Button x:Name="SavePreset_Button" Content="Save" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"></Button>
    <Button x:Name="DeletePreset_Button" Content="Delete" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0"></Button>
    <!-- Reasoning -->
    <Label Content="Begründung" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"></Label>
    <TextBox x:Name="Reasoning_TextBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" MinLines="2" MaxLines="2" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxLength="200"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MinLines and MaxLines on TextBox not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322182/minlines-and-maxlines-on-textbox-not-working)

Comment: You could read the LineCount property of the TextBox on the TextChanged event

Comment: Or you could just use two TextBoxes which would make it easier for you. And it also allows the user to see which text is displayed in which line.

Comment: @PalleDue thank you for the suggestion. It is a Workaround.

Comment: @MichaelRath using the TextChanged event seems to the the way to go. I hoped for an in built solution. thank you for the suggestion. 2 Textboxes are not good, the user would have to switch and wrap around not so easily possible.

Comment: @julianbechtold: Yes, it's a workaround, but it doesn't seem as though there is any good, working solution.

Comment: @julianbechtold: If you want to display two lines, why don't you set the `Height`? What's the difference?

Comment: If you need to prevent the user from entering more than two lines, then the only way is to control the user input.
At the View level, this is easiest to do in the TextChanged event.
At the ViewModel level, this can be done in the property setter.

Comment: The MinLines, MaxLines, Height, MinHeight, MaxHeight properties control only the VISIBLE part of the TextBox.
In this case, the user is unlimited in the water of any number of lines.
By setting the above properties, you can hide some of the content of the TextBox, but the content will be larger than the displayed text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After being loaded to visual tree, if `TextBox` is blank, `DesiredSize` will contain the height of one line plus the height of other causes, and `ExtentHeight` will contain the height of one line. We can use this two to calculate the actual height we need. In your case, it will be like

```
<TextBox x:Name="Reasoning_TextBox" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" MaxLines="2" TextWrapping="Wrap"
         Loaded="Reasoning_TextBox_Loaded"></TextBox>

private void Reasoning_TextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBox t = (TextBox)sender;
    t.Height = t.DesiredSize.Height + t.ExtentHeight * (t.MaxLines - 1);
}
```