# WPF Control size is not the same as design at runtime

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, visual-studio-2022

I am creating a WPF application based on a book using Visual Studio 2022 Community. The problem is with how the UI looks different at runtime.

The problem is with the TextBox at the bottom. It only looks like what it suppose to after i try to resize the window a little.

**Designer**:
[image]

**Running**:
[image]

Here is my XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="FontViewer.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FontViewer"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Font Viewer" Height="480" Width="800">
    <DockPanel>
        <Border DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                CornerRadius="6"
                BorderThickness="1"
                BorderBrush="Gray"
                Background="LightGray"
                Padding="8"
                Margin="4 4 4 4"
        >
            <TextBlock FontSize="14"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap">
                Select a font to view from the list below.
                You can change the text by typing in the region at the bottom.
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>
        <ListBox x:Name="FontList"
                 DockPanel.Dock="Left"
                 ItemsSource="{x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}"
                 Width="160"
                 Margin="4 4 0 4"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="SampleText"
                 DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"
                 MinLines="4"
                 Margin="8 0 8 4"
                 TextWrapping="Wrap"
                 ToolTip="Type here to change the preview text.">
            The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
        </TextBox>
        <StackPanel Margin="8 4 8 4">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=SampleText, Path=Text}" 
                       FontFamily="{Binding ElementName=FontList, Path=SelectedItem}"
                       FontSize="10"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Margin="0 0 0 4"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=SampleText, Path=Text}" 
                       FontFamily="{Binding ElementName=FontList, Path=SelectedItem}"
                       FontSize="16"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Margin="0 0 0 4"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=SampleText, Path=Text}" 
                       FontFamily="{Binding ElementName=FontList, Path=SelectedItem}"
                       FontSize="24"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Margin="0 0 0 4"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=SampleText, Path=Text}" 
                       FontFamily="{Binding ElementName=FontList, Path=SelectedItem}"
                       FontSize="32"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Margin="0 0 0 4"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

I have tried to mess around with the Margin but still in vain.

Do you know the how to fix this?

Comment: The only thing I see different between those two images is the window chrome.  You are going to have to be more specific as to what you think is wrong.  The designer is just a general idea of what it will look like, but the OS is going to have it's say.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, I'll edit it right now. The problem is with the TextBox at the bottom. I don't know why it look so small like that when i run the app. I want it to look exactly like in the designer without having to resize the app.

Comment: Sounds like the same as this other [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22322182/minlines-and-maxlines-on-textbox-not-working)